# How does a postgres lock get released on exception

Tags: postgresql, exception, locking

I am writing a function which locks onto a table and performs update operation. And here I am using an extension to hash a string and here there is a chance of an error.

Now my question is. How do I make sure the lock is released in case of an exception?

I am using the lock in "IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE "mode.

Comment: Cross post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/145708/1822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lock typically is released at the end of the transaction. As a function can't do transaction handling you can't really release the lock **in** the function. The code that calls the function must properly commit or rollback the transaction in order to release the lock.

Another option is to use a savepoint *before* acquiring the lock. In that case you can rollback to the savepoint in the exception handler to release the lock.

```
begin
  savepoint before_lock;
  lock table foo in exclusive mode;
  ... do stuff
exception 
   when others then 
     rollback to before_lock;
end;
```

Note that this will not release the lock in case everything is OK (nor will the current transaction be ended). You still need to end the transaction in the code that calls the function

Comment: In case everything is OK, I am calling the function in a Begin-Commit; block. Will that end the transaction?BEGIN;
 LOCK TABLE my_table IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
 SELECT my_function();
COMMIT;

Comment: @MukundGandlur: if you commit or rollback from the calling code, the savepoint inside the function is not really needed. Just make sure you do end the transaction properly.

Comment: you can also cancel the function's execution from another session by using `pg_cancel_backend ( <_pid_of the_function_calling_session_> )` and trap this exception `query_canceled` in your function ... when arriving in the function's exception handler the locks will no longer be held by the function's transaction, it seems from my investigation, and you can re-raise another exception / warning if you like ... i would like to give example of this as an answer, but no time now .. later, i hope